# How to assign a name to an Excel cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to assign a unique name to a cell which calls a particular user defined function.

I tried

```
Dim r As Range
set r = Application.Caller

r.Name = "Unique"
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code sets cell A1 to have the name 'MyUniqueName':

```
Private Sub NameCell()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1")
rng.Name = "MyUniqueName"

End Sub
```

Does that help?

**EDIT**

I am not sure how to achieve what you need in a simple way, elegant way. I did manage this hack - see if this helps but you'd most likely want to augment my solution.

Suppose I have the following user defined function in VBA that I reference in a worksheet:

```
Public Function MyCustomCalc(Input1 As Integer, Input2 As Integer, Input3 As Integer) As Integer

MyCustomCalc = (Input1 + Input2) - Input3

End Function
```

Each time I call this function I want the cell that called that function to be assigned a name. To achieve this, if you go to 'ThisWorkbook' in your VBA project and select the 'SheetChange' event then you can add the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Left$(Target.Formula, 13) = "=MyCustomCalc" Then
    Target.Name = "MyUniqueName"
End If
End Sub
```

In short, this code checks to see if the calling range is using the user defined function and then assigns the range a name (MyUniqueName) in this instance.

As I say, the above isn't great but it may give you a start. I couldn't find a way to embed code into the user defined function and set the range name directly e.g. using `Application.Caller.Address` or `Application.Caller.Cells(1,1)` etc. I am certain there is a way but I'm afraid I am a shade rusty on VBA...

Comment: There is another (though less friendly) way to add a named range: ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="myName", RefersToR1C1:=MyArea. See http://www.mrexcel.com/td0131.html

Answer (score 0):

I used this sub to work its way across the top row of a worksheet and if there is a value in the top row it sets that value as the name of that cell. It is VBA based so somewhat crude and simple, but it does the job!!

```
Private Sub SortForContactsOutlookImport()

    Dim ThisCell As Object
    Dim NextCell As Object
    Dim RangeName As String

    Set ThisCell = ActiveCell
    Set NextCell = ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)

    Do
        If ThisCell.Value <> "" Then
            RangeName = ThisCell.Value
            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=ThisCell
            Set ThisCell = NextCell
            Set NextCell = ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If

    Loop Until ThisCell.Value = "Web Page"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this sub, without formal error handling:

```
Sub NameAdd()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nameString, rangeString, sheetString As String

    On Error Resume Next

    rangeString = "A5:B8"
    nameString = "My_Name"
    sheetString = "Sheet1"

    Set rng = Worksheets(sheetString).Range(rangeString)

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add name:=nameString, RefersTo:=rng

End Sub
```

To Delete a Name:

```
Sub NameDelete()
    Dim nm As name

    For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
        If nm.name = "My_Name" Then nm.Delete
   Next

End Sub
```